# Random Forest predictions in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm trying to wrap my head around why I get different predictions in R for the following situation:

```
Model <- randomForest(response ~ variables, data = MY_DATA)

predict(Model, type = 'response')[1]
```

> 0.007752

```
predict(Model, type = 'response', newdata = MY_DATA[1,])
```

> 0.007887

Shouldn't these lines produce the same result since they're predicting from the same variable values?

Answer (score 5):

The first approach provides the out-of-bag prediction, while the second one gives you the insample prediction. In most cases, it is the first approach you should work with when studying the model performance.